# Issue in reading data frames in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot my data set based on the changes over years. My code

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Year   impact
2017    1
2016    0.065037954
2016    0.102155159
2015    0.030964478
2015    0.100059625
2015    0.089210196
2014    0.034352628
2014    0.080435423
2012    0.054331258
2011    0.052896022
2011    0.087341494
2010    0.025212239
2010    0.0456487
',header=TRUE)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Year)) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle("Test")+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Probability")
```

the x-axis should show years (2017 2016 ...) and the y-axis should show the values (minimum 0 and maximum 1). Is there any mistake in my code?

**EDIT**
the out put `dput(df)` as follow:

```
structure(list(Yearimpact = c(20171, 20160.065037954, 20160.102155159, 
20160.030964478, 20160.100059625, 20160.089210196, 20160.034352628, 
20160.080435423, 20160.054331258, 20160.052896022, 20160.087341494, 
20160.025212239, 20160.0456487)), .Names = "Yearimpact", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: Yes, there is. You're missing argument `text` as in `read.table(text = '`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas still the data become concatenated. and I did not show the results. also it give error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Year' not found
`

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(df)`?

Comment: I get a graph showing years on x and values from 0 to 0.15 on y. Sounds like you want to use `scale_y_continuous` to adjust y.

Comment: @RuiBarradas i have updated the question with the `dput(df)`

Comment: It seems you have null or other non-printable characters as column separators in your data.

Comment: how to overcome this issue? any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Using fread() from the **data.table** package is simpler, reads large datasets faster, and typically results in fewer errors. Try this instead:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

df <- fread("Year   impact
             2017    1
             2016    0.065037954
             2016    0.102155159
             2015    0.030964478
             2015    0.100059625
             2015    0.089210196
             2014    0.034352628
             2014    0.080435423
             2012    0.054331258
             2011    0.052896022
             2011    0.087341494
             2010    0.025212239
             2010    0.0456487")
```

If you need to convert this data table to a data frame for some reason afterword, you can use this:

```
df <- data.frame(df)
```

Either way, you can then graph the data:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Year)) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle("Test")+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Probability")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works for the example, but in my real data, when i copy and paste it in the same example, it show the `df` as `Yearimpact` not separate them `Year impact` how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Sultan - What's separating your columns? Try adding sep="," if it's a comma (CSV file); add sep=" " if separated by a space, etc. Help for the fread function can be found by running ?fread.

Comment: I use `df <- fread("clusters-analysis.csv",sep="," )` and it gives the same issues, the x-axis shows the years like `2007.5 2010.0 2012.5 ...` which affects the plot results

Comment: @Sultan - Check for spaces or special characters (e.g. %$&) in column names, which can't be there. Check for commas in numeric values, which can't be there. Spaces in values may also cause issues.